# Product Request for IAP in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I an trying to set up the product request for my IAP in my app, I am having issues defining rhe request correctly. Here is the code:

```
let productsRequest: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: self.productId as! Set<String>)
```

self.productRequest is the string identifier for the IAP created in itunesConnect

It gives the error

> Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'Set' always fails

What am i supposed to be passing into a request if not the identifying string of the IAP? I run the app and it returns 0 products

EDIT: new full func code:

```
let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = ["com.Personal.LiftApp.RemoveGoogleAds"]
        let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because `ProductIdentifier` must be a string :

```
typealias ProductIdentifier = String
```

and you should pass a set of strings:

```
let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
```

So, you should call:

```
productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
```

To help you to better understand how to make it, look this example:

```
let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = [id_of_the_first_in_app_purchase, id_of_the_second_in_app_purchase]
```

Comment: Thanks i have edited the OP with my code now, this runs but returns 0 results still, am I to assume this is due to a id issue now rather than the function?

Comment: Your in-app purchase elements must be approved by apple, then you can see these elements available to test or publishing

Comment: but my app hasnt reached release yet to be approved, if i cant test them at all prior to release, how do i know they will work? I thought there was a sandbox to test

Comment: You can test it also from the test flight service, but in-app purchases elements don't follow the app state, are elements approved apart from the app flow..

Comment: so is it possible for me to submit just this 1 IAP for approval since its just disabling adverts?

Comment: Sure, all your in-app purchase elements could be sended to approval during your app development.